# Go: Sort array, dropping elements if error caught in `Less(i, j int)`

Tags: arrays, sorting, go

Given the following `struct`

```
type Point struct {
    datetimeRecorded time.Time
}

// Returns true if the point was recorded before the comparison point.
// If datetime is not available return false and an error
func (p1 Point) RecordedBefore(p2 Point) (isBefore bool, err error) {
    if (p1.datetimeRecorded.IsZero()) || (p2.datetimeRecorded.IsZero()) {
        err = ErrNoDatetime
    } else {
        isBefore = p1.datetimeRecorded.Before(p2.datetimeRecorded)
    }
    return
}
```

I would like to sort a `[]Point` by the `datetimeRecorded` attribute.

I have the following (which works):

```
type ByDatetimeRecorded []Point

func (a ByDatetimeRecorded) Len() int {
    return len(a)
}

func (a ByDatetimeRecorded) Swap(i, j int) {
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
}

func (a ByDatetimeRecorded) Less(i, j int) bool {
    swap, _ := a[i].RecordedBefore(a[j])
    return swap
}
```

However, if the `datetimeRecorded` attribute is not initialised in either comparison an `error` will be caught and the points not swapped (returns `false`).

Is it possible to catch this error and drop it from the array? Something like:

```
func (a ByDatetimeRecorded) Less(i, j int) bool {
    swap, err := a[i].RecordedBefore(a[j])
    if err != nil {
        // Remove element here
    }
    return swap
}
```

**Edit 1**

I may have to be more specific about what element to drop so this may make more sense:

```
func (a ByDatetimeRecorded) Less(i, j int) bool {
    if a[i].datetimeRecorded.IsZero() {
        // Drop a[i]
    }
    if a[j].datetimeRecorded.IsZero() {
        // Drop a[j]
    }
    swap, _ := a[i].RecordedBefore(a[j])
    return swap
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard sort package will not drop elements from the slice.
Filter the zero values out of the slice before sorting.

```
  i := 0
  for _, p := range points {
      if !p.datetimeRecorded.IsZero() {
         points[i] = p
         i++
      }
  }
  points = points[:i]
  sort.Sort(ByDatetimeRecorded(points))
```

Comment: Do it in two steps: strip incorrect items; sort culled slice. Otherwise you are doing two things in one function and that is not a good idea.